# Actual time of "nativeGetTimestamp" in "SurfaceTexture"

Tags: android, surface

I'm writing a video processing app and need to know the actual time of each frame.

The app works fine at first when I used `elapsedRealtime` To compute the time offset:

```
long timeOffset = java.lang.System.currentTimeMillis() - android.os.SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
long actualTime = timestamp + timeOffset;
```

But when I used another device, I found some device will use `uptimeMillis` for the SurfaceTexture.timestamp, so the code sould be:

```
long timeOffset = java.lang.System.currentTimeMillis() - android.os.SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
long actualTime = timestamp + timeOffset;
```

So my question is, **is there any way to know which time source are the device use for SurfaceTexture**?

Although I may compute the closest time source at start of app, but I think it may cause another accident that I can't know yet.

Is there any way to know that?

Answer (score 1):

MediaCodec doesn't invent the timestamps. The buffers that MediaCodec return only contain the same values for `presentationTimeUs` as you pass in the `presentationTimeUs` parameter to `queueInputBuffer`, or when using `Surface` input, is set on the input surface using `eglPresentationTimeANDROID`.

So you need to check with whichever piece of code that actually produces the timestamps to know what time reference they use.

Comment: I found my timestamp is made by `nativeGetTimestamp` of `SurfaceTexture`, could you tell me how to know the time source of SurfaceTexture?

Comment: What is filling in the content in the SurfaceTexture? If it is e.g. MediaCodec decoding into it, the timestamps come from the input data to that MediaCodec decoder.

Comment: My SurfaceTexture context is Camera!

Comment: Then this is not a MediaCodec question, but a Camera API question. I don't know off-hand about that, unfortunately.

Comment: your information is really helpful, I'll keep looking for the answer!