# MediaCodec encode video with inputSurface but drop frames

Tags: android, encode, android-mediacodec, surface

I'm looking for the fastest way to "decode edit encode" video on Android devices. So I choose MediaCodec with Surface for Input And Output.

This is my idea:
1. decode the mp4 file with MediaCoder, the output is SurfaceTexture;
2. use OpenGL's to edit surface, the output is texture;
3. use MediaCodec to encode, the input is Surface

the problem is:
**decode and edit are much faster than encode**, so when I had decode and edit 50 frames, encode maybe just consume 10 frames. but as I use the surface for input with Encode, I don't know if the encoder has consumed all previous frames. so the 40 frames are lost.

Is there any way let me know the surface consume state, so I can control decode speed or any other idea?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Actual time of "nativeGetTimestamp" in "SurfaceTexture"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52511236/actual-time-of-nativegettimestamp-in-surfacetexture)